# Deploy a pre-compiled RStan model and avoid recompilation

Tags: shiny, rstan

I've been at this for hours now.

I compile a stan model with the following code:

```
model <- stan(file = "model.stan", data = data, save_dso = FALSE, chains = 4, cores = 4, iter = 2000, warmup = 1000)
```

When I `ls` the current directory, I see `model.rds` whereas I didn't see it before. All is good thus far.

Subsequently, I refit this model with new parameters via:

```
fit <- stan(file = "model.stan",  data = new.data, chains = 1, cores = 1, iter = 4000, warmup = 2000)
```

This code is running in a Shiny app. Locally, all works as expected.

When I deploy this app to shinyapps.io, the model tries to recompile (resulting in a g++ error - presumably from lack of sufficient memory). Irrespective, I don't want this model to recompile in the first place: I'd like it to use the `model.rds` object I'd already built. Yes, I do include this object in the files uploaded to the shinyapps.io server.

I feel like I've tried all the things - including loading `model.rds` explicitly with `loadRDS` and passing it into the `stan(fit = model ...` call. What am I missing?

For completeness, below is the error I received on the shinyapps.io end. Again, I don't wish for this model to go about recompiling in the first place.

`Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/config.hpp:39:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/rev/core/var.hpp:7,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/rev/core/gevv_vvv_vari.hpp:5,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/rev/core.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/rev/mat.hpp:4,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math.hpp:4,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders/include/src/stan/model/model_header.hpp:4,
                 from file137729fa09.cpp:8:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include/boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp:186:0: warning: "BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES" redefined [enabled by default]
 #  define BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make: *** [file137729fa09.o] Error 4`

Comment: The gcc error comes from an option that allows redefining on your desktop and not on the server. It is related to BH. I found that closed issue : https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/372

Comment: I believe that's just a warning - I've been getting identical warnings locally, but my models still compile and run fine.

On the server, the error would be `g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)` - two lines below. This said, I don't want the model to go about recompiling at all: I'd like it to use the pre-compiled model I'm uploading [to the server] with the code.

Comment: It's quite unlikely that a binary produced by gcc on your desktop would run on shinyapps.io server. I'd try using another model that doesn't need compiling.